# How can I convert pixel data in QImage to another format?

Tags: c++, qt, format, qt5, qimage

I receive an instance of `QImage` with arbitrary `QImage::Format`. How can I create another instance of `QImage` with a particular `QImage::Format` of my choosing so that the actual image data is converted from the arbitrary format to my format?

Example:

```
QImage convertFormat(const QImage &inputImage, QImage::format outputFormat)
{
    // What comes here?
}

//Usage
QImage converted = convertFormat(mySourceImage, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
```

I am looking for a way to do this with existing code in Qt if possible (as opposed to writing my own pixel format conversion routines working on the low level).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use [convertToFormat](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#convertToFormat)? It has nearly the same syntax as you requested, though it's a member of `QImage` so you'd only pass in the format.

Comment: LOL Can't beleive I didn't see that!

Comment: I was all cross-eyed apparently. The real question was different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43106069/how-to-convert-qvideoframe-with-yuv-data-to-qvideoframe-with-rgba32-data-in