# How to convert 'QVideoFrame' with YUV data to 'QVideoframe' with RGBA32 data in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, format, qt5, qtmultimedia

I receive `QVideoFrames` from webcam, and they contain image data in **YUV** format (`QVideoFrame::Format_YUV420P`). How can I convert one such frame to one with `QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32` or `QVideoFrame::Format_RGBA32`?

Can I do it without going low level, using just existing functionality in **Qt5**?

Example:

```
QVideoFrame convertFormat(const QVideoFrame &inputframe, QVideoFrame::PixelFormat outputFormat)
{
    // What comes here?
}

//Usage
QVideoFrame converted = convertFormat(mySourceFrame, QVideoFrame::Format_RGB32);
```

Comment: NOTE: Somewhat related but for QImage. I asked this first before realizing what I really wanted was conversion of data in QVideoFrames http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43105753/how-can-i-convert-pixel-data-in-qimage-to-another-format/43105841#43105841

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that is *built into Qt5*, but **UNSUPPORTED BY Qt**.

Here is how to go about:

1. Put `QT += multimedia-private` into your qmake .pro file
2. Put `#include "private/qvideoframe_p.h"` into your code to make the function available.
3. You now have access to a function with the following signature: `QImage qt_imageFromVideoFrame(const QVideoFrame &frame);`
4. Use the function to convert the `QVideoFrame` to a temporay `QImage` and then create the output `QVideoFrame` from that image.

Here is my example usage:

```
QVideoFrame convertFormat(const QVideoFrame &inputframe, QVideoFrame::PixelFormat outputFormat)
    {
        inputframe->map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
        QImage tempImage=qt_imageFromVideoFrame(inputframe);
        inputframe->unmap();
        QVideoFrame outputFrame=QVideoFrame(tempImage);
        return outputFrame;
    }
```

Again, the warning copied from the header reads as follows:

> ```
> //
> //  W A R N I N G
> //  -------------
> //
> // This file is not part of the Qt API.  It exists purely as an
> // implementation detail.  This header file may change from version to
> // version without notice, or even be removed.
> //
> // We mean it.
> //
> ```

This does not matter in my project since it is a personal toy product. If it ever gets serious I will just track down the implementation of that function and copy it into my project or something.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a YUV --> RGB conversion solution in [the linked comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829830/convert-qvideoframe-to-qimage#comment49984060_27830041),

So Implementing the **supportedPixelFormats** function like the following example does the magic of converting even **YUV based formats** (in my case, it converted a *Format_YUV420P* format) into the **Format_RGB24** format:

```
QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>MyVideoSurface::
supportedPixelFormats(QAbstractVideoBuffer::HandleType handleType) const
{
    Q_UNUSED(handleType);
    return QList<QVideoFrame::PixelFormat>()
        << QVideoFrame::Format_RGB24
    ;
}
```

Tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: Quite funny, I wrote that comment that you linked to :) I haven't had a chance to test this.

Answer (score -2):

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#map

```
if (inputframe.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly))
{
    int height = inputframe.height();
    int width = inputframe.width();
    uchar* bits = inputframe.bits();
    // figure out the inputFormat and outputFormat, they should be QImage::Format
    QImage image(bits, width, height, inputFormat);
    // do your conversion
    QImage outImage = image.convertToForma(outFormat); // blah convert
    return QVideoFrame(outImage);
}
```

Comment: Just a dumb question, since YUV isn't among the formats supported by QImage, will the line QImage image(bits, width, height, inputFormat); work?

Comment: Right, when I did this, I converted QVideoFrame to OpenCV Mat first.